# How do I display google chrome's menus in xubuntu? I can't find them

Tags: xubuntu, google-chrome, xfce

I can't file the "File Edit View..." menus in google chrome in xfce (xubuntu)! How do I display them or where are they? ...I'm surprised I'm asking such a question XD

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/850562/some-applications-display-their-menus-in-unity-but-not-in-xfce-how-can-i-make-x

Answer (score -2):

I don't believe there are any menus for Chrome outside of the button on the top right, the "hamburger" button as they call it. As far as I recall you get to everything from there.

Comment: hehehehe no there are buttons :D (p.s; sorry for the minus one, wasn't from me)

Comment: There **are** buttons. They are displayed in Unity. It should be possible to get them displayed in Xfce too.