# Some applications display their menus in Unity but not in Xfce. How can I make Xfce display them too?

Tags: 16.04, xfce, menu, panel

Some applications display their menus (File, edit, etc.) in Unity but not in Xfce. Some example screenshots from Unity:

**Mozilla Firefox:**

[image]

**Google Chrome:**

[image]

---

However, these applications don't display these menus in Xfce. I have enabled a [global TopMenu](https://askubuntu.com/a/850543/451919) on Xfce, but that does not make these applications display their menus.

Since these very same applications **do** display these menus in Unity, they are indeed available. But how can I enable them in Xfce?

I have read "[Application menus missing in Xubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779337/application-menus-missing-in-xubuntu)" and "[How do I display google chrome's menus in xubuntu? I can't find them](https://askubuntu.com/questions/499620/how-do-i-display-google-chromes-menus-in-xubuntu-i-cant-find-them)". There are no suitable answers there. Also, this question is about the general phenomenon, not just the individual apps. Also, I want to specifically emphasise that these menus **do** appear in Unity, which means that they are indeed available.

Answer (score 1):

If you open Firefox and then press the 'Alt' key, the menu appears. The menu does seem to disappear once you have used it. However, if you select View->Toolbars from the menu and ensure "Menu Bar" is ticked, the menu remains permanently. There may be an easier way but this seems to work.

Not sure if the same works for Chrome.